# Inferring order based on similar but non-overlapping columns

Tags: r, matrix

Does there exist a standardized R function that given a matrix where the columns contain the rownames of a series of individual data frames:

```
Example Input
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "A"  "A"  "B" 
[2,] "B"  "C"  "C" 
[3,] "C"  "D"  "D" 
[4,] "D"  "E"  "F"
```

Will infer the "overall" row ordering, and output this instead:

```
     [,1]
[1,] "A" 
[2,] "B" 
[3,] "C" 
[4,] "D" 
[5,] "E" 
[6,] "F"
```

I need to join multiple data frames that are all similar to each other, but no one data frames contains one of each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `m` is your matrix, you can do the following.

```
m2 <- matrix(unique(as.vector(m)), ncol = 1)
m2
#     [,1]
# [1,] "A" 
# [2,] "B" 
# [3,] "C" 
# [4,] "D" 
# [5,] "E" 
# [6,] "F"
```

**DATA**

```
m <- matrix(c( "A",  "A",  "B", 
               "B",  "C",  "C", 
               "C",  "D",  "D", 
               "D",  "E",  "F" ),
            ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
```

Comment: Does this generally preserve the original ordering of the rows?

Comment: @MichaelYu I think, Yes. The order is preserved.